# how to batch several swaps in a single tx (batch tx)?

Tags: batch

Hi I wanna purchase several erc20 tokens to build a portofolio but gas prices are just exorbitant since several weeks, so I'd like to find a way to implement swapping mutliple assets in a single tx (uniswap, 1inch or any solution to get the best rates/save on slippage)

If you have any documentations about how to do it in javascript/python that would be great (learning solidity for the moment so surely for a v2 but I'll welcome any infos on it as well of course)

If you even have some working code example and kindly explain how it works under the hood would also be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: See my [PRBProxy](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

check out Materia DEX. They are preparing this funcionality. It will be in production soon. However, this DEX is still in its early stages. But batch swap in materia dex will be able to route through other Dex’s for liquidity. So low liquidity might not be a problem from the start Best

Answer (score 0):

Lately, there has been a dApp out there Dzap: https://dzap.io you can check it out. They allow batching multiple transactions into a single transaction. They have been getting quite some traction.